# assigning groups of ID values to a number of rows in R

Tags: r

I have the following data in the form;

```
                               Major.sectors     EBIT.CAP
1                   Food, beverages, tobacco  -0.29998599
2 Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling -10.11204781
3                               Construction  -0.05840266
4                       Publishing, printing   1.56335275
5                             Other services  -1.87696308
6                       Hotels & restaurants  -0.93189920
```

I am trying to assign an ID to a number of sectors. For example, assign an ID in a new column such as; `Group 1` which would be assigned to `Food, beverages, tabacco` and `Publishing, printing` and `Other services` then a group ID `Group 2` value to `Construction` and `Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling` etc.

Dput example, first 40 rows:

```
structure(list(Major.sectors = c("Food, beverages, tobacco", 
"Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", "Construction", 
"Publishing, printing", "Other services", "Hotels & restaurants", 
"Wholesale & retail trade", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Wholesale & retail trade", 
"Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", 
"Transport", "Construction", "Other services", "Hotels & restaurants", 
"Transport", "Construction", "Other services", "Construction", 
"Wholesale & retail trade", "Construction", "Transport", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
"Wholesale & retail trade", "Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling", 
"Wood, cork, paper", "Construction", "Other services", "Other services", 
"Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Food, beverages, tobacco", 
"Construction", "Wholesale & retail trade", "Transport", "Education, Health", 
"Chemicals, rubber, plastics, non-metallic products", "Construction", 
"Construction"), EBIT.CAP = c(-0.299985988510579, -10.112047808544, 
-0.0584026622296173, 1.56335274542429, -1.87696308048616, -0.931899204244032, 
0.118490171376958, -0.620735294117647, 0.825160979018652, -0.0531417228115857, 
5.04349258649094, 8.46722129783694, -1.56569551556698, 0.288562019546801, 
-8.17965612867443, -67.3093602404465, -0.590864600326264, -10.2089108910891, 
-2.84859771783905, 27.06476, -3.23294509151414, -0.262818510268391, 
-3.83117723156533, 12.2774086378738, -0.0961711136674632, 0.0444317163701523, 
-1.72438062594632, -0.0790666666666667, -0.166531914893617, -203.16001330672, 
NA, 11.203993344426, -0.0368548170677163, -34.8521655213724, 
-354.333333333333, -0.682595842695865, 1.59589572933999, -1.7513907638213, 
12.7705882352941, 2.36404166666667)), .Names = c("Major.sectors", 
"EBIT.CAP"), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:

How I hope the final result will look like.

```
                               Major.sectors     EBIT.CAP    Group
1                   Food, beverages, tobacco  -0.29998599    Group 1
2 Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling -10.11204781    Group 2
3                               Construction  -0.05840266    Group 2
4                       Publishing, printing   1.56335275    Group 1
5                             Other services  -1.87696308    Group 1
6                       Hotels & restaurants  -0.93189920    Group 3
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an ID for multiple elements as a group?

Comment: I am trying to `group` a number of rows together by assigning an `ID` value such as `group 1`, `group 2` etc. So  `group 1` will have `Food, beverages, tabacco` and also `Publishing, printing` along with `Other services` it may be called `group 1`.

Comment: thanks, in that case, it is a custom grouping, so you may need to create a key/value dataset (updated my solution) and then do a join

Comment: Updated the original post for final output

Comment: If you check my output, it is working fine.  Only thing is that all the group keys need to be created i nthe keyval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.GRP` from `data.table` to create the grouping IDs

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, GroupID := paste0("Group", .GRP), Major.sectors]
```

---

Or using a similar option from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(GroupID = paste0("Group", group_indices(., Major.sectors)))
```

---

If the objective is to cluster multiple 'Major.sectors' (custom) to a single group, then we create a key/value dataset and then do a `left_join`

```
keyval = data.frame(GroupID = c('Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 2'), 
    Major.sectors = c('Food, beverages, tobacco', 'Publishing, printing',

  'Other services', 'Construction', 
   'Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
left_join(df1, keyval) %>%
        head

#                               Major.sectors     EBIT.CAP GroupID
#1                   Food, beverages, tobacco  -0.29998599 Group 1
#2 Machinery, equipment, furniture, recycling -10.11204781 Group 2
#3                               Construction  -0.05840266 Group 2
#4                       Publishing, printing   1.56335275 Group 1
#5                             Other services  -1.87696308 Group 1
#6                       Hotels & restaurants  -0.93189920    <NA>
```

The 6th is empty because 'keyval' dataset is incomplete

Comment: Thanks! It seems kind of involved for what I thought would have been a simpler task, I will play and adjust you code and see if it works!

Comment: @user113156  If your grouping doesn't have any pattern then you need to built a key/value

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it work with the whole of the data, I really appreciate your help I will certainly be saving this code for future reference!